# Como agregar y remover una clase? Jquery

Tags: jquery

CSS

```
.color{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Js

```
  $("#drawer").on("click",".picker",function(){
            var element = $(this);
            $(element).removeClass('color');
            $(element).addClass('color');
        });
```

quiero agregarle color o removerselo pero solo pinta mas no remueve.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres utilizando `toggleClass()` asi:

```js
 $("#drawer").on("click",".picker",function(){
            var element = $(this);
            $(element).toggleClass('color');
            
        });
```

```css
.color{
    background-color:blue;
}
Js
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drawer"><button class="picker">Hello</button></div>
```

Comment: Hola, si funciona, pero si quiero limitarlo a 2 clicks como máximo, cosa que cuando llegue al 3er click despinte 1 de los 2 pintandos . por eso pensaba hacerlo con el add clas y remove.

Comment: En ese caso deberias de agregar todo tu codigo y una explicacion de lo que quieres hacer exactamente.